# How to configure external cmake libraries?

Tags: cmake

What I wanted to do is call

```
add_subdirectory(ext/oglplus)
```

and be done with it. Unfortunately it is not that simple. There is a huge buildscript which detects various opengl settings. So I tried the following

```
ExternalProject_Add(liboglplus
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/oglplus
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/oglplus/configure.py --use-glew
    BUILD_COMMAND  ${MAKE})
```

The problem that I have is don't really want to build it like that. It also doesn't build correctly because for some reason it wants to install the library and because there is no install target it will abort the compilation.

But the build script is calling cmake under the hood.

So what I want to do is to tell cmake to use "cofigure.py" instead of "cmake .." and then use it like any other cmake library.

Is this possible?

Comment: The install error should go away if you add `INSTALL_COMMAND ""` to the `ExternalProject_Add` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to call Linux Kernel KBuild from CMake using 
`ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND()` and `ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET()`
This way you can run arbitrary commands (like your config.py) and use the output.

First setup the command with all command-line options as CMake-variables, in tou case this would be calling the `config.py` script `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/oglplus/`.
Instead of encoding the Path to your script in the command (adding `ext/oglplus`) I think it may be better adding `WORKING_DIRECTORY` to the custom command:
[add_custom_command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html)

```
SET(KBUILD_CMD ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM}
-C ${KERNEL_BUILD_DIR}
CROSS_COMPILE=${CROSS_COMPILE} ARCH=${ARCH}
EXTRA_CFLAGS=${KBUILD_EXTRA_CFLAGS}
INSTALL_MOD_PATH=${INSTALL_MOD_PATH}
M=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS=${depends_module_ksyms}
)
```

Add a custom command that calls your build-script and creates a file in the `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIRECTORY` (note the second `COMMAND` to touch a file)

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
OUTPUT  ${module_name}.built
COMMAND ${KBUILD_CMD} modules
COMMAND cmake -E touch ${module_name}.built
COMMENT "Kernel make modules ${module_name}"
VERBATIM
)
```

Add a custom target, its always out of date, but if you want it to be called automatically add `ALL` otherwise you have to explicityly call `make module_build`, I guess this is what you want.

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET("${module_name}_build" ALL
DEPENDS  ${depends_module_ksyms}
${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${module_name}.built
COMMENT "Building Kernel Module ${module_name}"
)
```